# How does select and group by execution works. Column present in GROUP BY and not in SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

According to documentations of MySQL I read SELECT executes before group by. I have a table named Views as follows and query

```
select distinct(viewer_id) as id
from Views v 
group by viewer_id,view_date
having count(distinct(article_id))>1;
```

In this query if select is performed before group by according to documentation,how is it able to group by based on view_date as only viewer_id is selected. This has really confused me about how exact order of group by and select work.

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| article_id | author_id | viewer_id | view_date  |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 1          | 3         | 5         | 2019-08-01 |
| 3          | 4         | 5         | 2019-08-01 |
| 1          | 3         | 6         | 2019-08-02 |
| 2          | 7         | 7         | 2019-08-01 |
| 2          | 7         | 6         | 2019-08-02 |
| 4          | 7         | 1         | 2019-07-22 |
| 3          | 4         | 4         | 2019-07-21 |
| 3          | 4         | 4         | 2019-07-21 |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not think in term of order of execution, but rather in terms of correctness of the statement. The `select` clause must be consistent with the `group by` clause: that is, any column that is present in the `select` clause and this is not part of an aggregate function must belong to the `group by` clause.

It is, on the other hand, perfectly valid to have columns in the `group by` clause that does not belong to the `select` clause - although the results might be a bit difficult to understand, because some information is missing about how the groups were built.

If we remove the `distinct` in the `select` clause, your query would phrase as:

```
select viewer_id as id
from views v 
group by viewer_id, view_date
having count(distinct(article_id)) > 1;
```

This brings the `viewer_id`s for every `view_date` when they have more than one distinct `article_id`. A given `viewer_id` may appear more than once in the resultset, if they satisfied the condition on more than one date.

Then, `distinct` filters out duplicates `viewer_id`s: as a result, you get the list of viewers that viewed more one article on *any date*.

Answer (score 0):

There is no order to the evaluation.  A SQL query describes the *result* set.

It is true that MySQL has a rather naive optimizer, so you can often see what the resulting query will be.  But you should not think of the clauses as being evaluated in a particular order.

You *might* be confusing evaluation of the query with scoping rules.  These affect how a particular identifier is determined.

Comment: I would say the there is an order to the evaluation based on the provided scope. For example [this Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jv2cFbJhYGuLcDnmoFz3Ca/0) in determining the value returned for `COALESCE()`. So knowing in which order the query is being evaluated to determine the identifier(s) can be confusing to beginners and what I believe the OP is trying to figure out.